# Installing The Free Version of EE2

Tags: ee2

I downloaded the free/basic version of ExpressionEngine2 just to get use to EE and all of its features. How would I go about installing / setting it up on my pc? Would I follow the same steps as the commercial one, just without entering the serial key?

I love that there's a free version for beginners to get use to the system and it's inner workings, even though it's very basic..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, EE Core installs and runs exactly the same as the full version: http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/installation/installation.html